# LilyPond: How can I compile a tweak macro?

Tags: lilypond

I’m trying to insert a new macro with the tweak command (`\tweak Accidental.restore-first ##t`) in my include-all file but it doesn't work.

The macro is: `restoreacc = \tweak Accidental.restore-first ##t`.   Strangely, Frescobaldi gives me an error in the macro after this whichever is the position of the macro.

For example, after this macro follows another macro: `mfine = mark markup { italic abs-fontsize #10 "End" }`  which works great if I don’t add this new macro.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What an assignment assigns is not some magic text replacement but one LilyPond expression.  `\tweak` is a music function call; the resulting music expression is not complete before the item to be tweaked is mentioned, so your definition of `restoreAcc` hoovers up `mfine` as the item to be tweaked and things go south from there.

Fortunately, there is a shortcut meaning "and as many arguments as would be needed to complete this music function call", namely `\etc`.

So you can get what you want by writing

```
restoreAcc = \tweak Accidental.restore-first ##t \etc
```